# What's the difference between cover letter and application email?

Tags: application

I am applying a position, which requires applicants to send cover letter and other materials by email. I think that in the application email I would present almost the same content in the cover letter: my interests in the job, my achievement, etc. So I am wondering that whether a cover letter as an attachment is still necessary or not. Any more information needed in the cover letter?

Answer (score 21):

Write a traditional cover letter and attach it to your email. The committee reviewing your application may not get forwarded your original email. They will probably get a packet sent to them that's prepared by a staff member that aggregates all the submissions. Your email can be short and sweet: "Dear Whoever, Here are my application materials for the position Professor of Blah Blah Blah as advertised at URL. Please see attached for all the requested documentation."

Comment: +1 Yes, in my discipline (anthropology) the cover letter serves as a short proxy for the research statement and is thus read very carefully.

Comment: I don't really make much use of them.

Comment: That's why I said "in my discipline."

Comment: Oh right, I'd love to get more examples here. I moved my comment about not using them from the answer to a comment.

Comment: OK, I've added my own answer to get at that diversity. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

A formal **cover letter** is necessary in some disciplines such as my own, where it serves as the short proxy for the research and teaching statement (i.e., you are expected in the space of 2 pages to summarize the significance of your research and if applying to a SLAC then the general focus of your teaching). There is great variance between disciplines though -- some require separate teaching and/or research statements. Ask your advisor what is appropriate for your field.

In any case, the **e-mail** containing the application itself can be short -- as the e-mail will often get deleted or otherwise not included in your file:

```
To: <search@ubermuda.edu>
Subject: Application for the junior position in sociocultural anthro (job #987)

Dear Search Committee

Please find enclosed my application for the junior faculty 
position in sociocultural anthropology at the University of  
the Bermudas (job posting #987). The attachments (enumerated...) 
are included in Adobe PDF format. 

Please let me know if any files are missing or cannot be opened.

Warmly,

Jane Smith

<attachments including cover letter, cv, etc.>
```

Comment: A sample cover letter for disciplines that use them can be found here: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/639/02/

Answer (score 1):

I believe generally there isn't any big difference between a cover letter and an application email except the length. In the email you can simply state for which position you are applying and why you are applying but in a cover letter you give more information about yourself, your skills and achievements. Also, in the email you should mention why you are qualified for the position. Well, I guess the same should be mentioned in a cover letter. But as I mentioned above length is the difference so keep your mail short and to the point but write a compellingly interesting cover letter.