# If a job ad asks for a research statement and a teaching statement, should I also include a cover letter?

Tags: application, job-search, job, faculty-application

A job I am applying to explicitly asks for a research statement, teaching statement and a CV. It doesn't mention a cover letter. Is it assumed that I will also include a cover letter?

Answer (score 2):

In some form, yes. What's probably implied is:

Don't attach it as a separate file and make it essentially the body of your email instead.

Related: [one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38613/whats-the-difference-between-cover-letter-and-application-email), [two](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/52132/in-email-applications-should-the-text-of-the-cover-letter-be-stated-directly-in).